# How to implement Google Auth Login in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, google-oauth, xamarin.forms

I am newbie in Xamarin, and Iwould like to have a Google login in my new app with Xamarin Forms. 
What is the right way? Is there any updated tutorial or video to guide? Where to start?

thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at the docs: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/ Pretty good walkthrough.

Comment: @JamesMontemagno, Is Xamarin.Auth work with Windows phone?

Comment: Yes it works with Windows phone but didn't work in iOS as Apple not allow browser based authentication from client app so batter you implement Platform specific code for the same because as per my knowledge Google is also don't allow browser based authentication in Android from client app in near future.

Comment: The Xamarin.Auth Problems should be fixed by now

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/) mentioned by [@JamesMontemagno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3085228/jamesmontemagno) (he is the best!), you can watch the video by Houssem Dellai for the same.

There is a also Xamarin cross-platform [component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) for the same.

Video: https://youtu.be/AgFIsVr26zg

GitHub: https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Google-Login-Xamarin-Forms/tree/master/GoogleLogin/GoogleLogin/Views

Hope it helps. Let me know.

Comment: While links may contain an answer, please write down the key points of your solution in this answer and explain it. Imagine that once those links expire your answer will be completely useless for any further visitor of this post.

Comment: I understand (and agree with) your point; but unfortunately, I haven't tried the solution myself. But wanted to help and thought the links were a good reference. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, another point. Please only post answers if you know that they solve OP's issue. It's a requirement that answers provide a working solution. :-) Otherwise a guess/hint/plain advice belongs to the comment section. Once you have enough reputation (I guess around 50) you will be able to comment on the question. By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow. :-)