# implementing google auth code in Xamarin forms project (not the authentication through google)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want google authentication for my Xamarin froms app

I have tried the soultions uploaded by Hossem dellai and I have tried the get and post method after creating client id and secret through google apis and got the access token but where do we implement the provided code in visual studio because there is no more portable class library and you cant create a webview as well.I have also tried with the xamarin.Auth nuget package and yet my issue isnt still resolved.All these last solutions have been updated atleast 3 years ago so need some fresh expert advise.Im using visual studio 2019.I want to know where exactly should I place the code in my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Google Auth Login in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367436/how-to-implement-google-auth-login-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: @FreakyAli My issue is the implementation within the visual studio project.

Comment: Your question seems a little vague if you could summarize it for me that would help

Comment: I have created a project in google console and got the keys and tokens necessary,now what I want is to know where in my xamarin forms project do I integrate the code that they have provided.

Comment: That is exactly what that answer does

Comment: you could check below,and there is a sample in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do most of the operations in **PCL** , and then you just need to do a callback in the **Android** or **ios** project(Close authorized page and Load redirectUrl page).

For example,Android **CallBack** like (you also could integrate on `MainActivity` and then get the data in the `OnNewIntent` method):

```
[Activity(Label = "ActivityCustomUrlSchemeInterceptor", NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
[IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataSchemes = new[] { "<your data scheme>" },
    DataPath = "/oauth2redirect")]
public class ActivityCustomUrlSchemeInterceptor : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Android.Net.Uri uri_android = Intent.Data;
        // Convert Android.Net.Url to Uri
        var uri = new Uri(uri_android.ToString());

        // Close browser 
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        //intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        StartActivity(intent);

        // Load redirectUrl page
        OAuthAuthenticatorHelper.AuthenticationState.OnPageLoading(uri);

        this.Finish();
    }
}
```

Ios is similar to this，you can refer to other more 
[AuthExample](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/someone1984-Xamarin.Auth-sample/AuthExample/AuthExample)